# Immutable class: The blank final field may not have been initialized

Tags: java, immutability

I have to do an immutable class but I'm given a mistake.

```
public final class ClassX{
   private final String a;
   private final String b;
   private final int c;


   public ClassX(String a, String b, int c){
       this.a=a;
       this.b=b;
       if(c>=1||c<=100)
       this.c=c;
   }
```

> The blank final field c may not have been initialized

Am I doing something wrong?

without if I don't get any errors but I need variable c to be in range 1-100

Comment: What should happen if it's not in range?

Comment: _I need variable c to be in range 1-100_ Then the `if` condition in your code is wrong. It will **always** return `true`. Maybe you should change the `||` to `&&`

Answer (score 4):

## Balance your `if` with an `else`

In your phrasing:

```java
if( … ) { this.c = c ; }
```

… you have not addressed the negative case. If the test in the `if` test results in a `false`, your member field `this.c` will not have been assigned a value by you. That member field of `int` will be assigned a default value of zero.

(For object references in contrast to primitives, the default will be `null`. That means no value at all in that member field.)

We can see this defaulting behavior in the following code example.

```java
package work.basil.example;

public class DefaultingInt
{
    private int count;

    public int getCount ( ) { return this.count; }  // Getter method (accessor). 

    @Override
    public String toString ( )
    {
        return "DefaultingInt{ " +
                "count=" + count +
                " }";
    }

    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        DefaultingInt di = new DefaultingInt();
        System.out.println( "di = " + di );
    }
}
```

When run:

> di = DefaultingInt{ count=0 }

With the code above, the value of the member field could always be changed later is some other code.

### `final` requires a value be assigned

Your code adds the complication of marking the member field `final`. Using `final` means that you intend to assign a value once, as a constant. The compiler ensures that no code is allowed to change that value.

Your [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment) or compiler is flagging an error because in the case of your `if` test returning `false`, you will not have assigned an explicit value to the `final` field. After the constructor ends, you cannot later assign a value. Since you insisted you would immediately set a single final value, and your code at runtime may miss your two chances to have set that value (static assignment, or in the constructor), the compiler knows something is wrong.

### Solution: Add `else`

To take care of the missing case when your `if` returns a `false`, change your code to add an `else` block.

```java
if( … ) { this.c = c ; } else { this.c = your-default-value-here ; }
```

As others pointed out, the logic of your particular `if` test is flawed. Use logical AND rather than OR.

```java
if( ( c >= 1 ) && ( c <= 100 ) )  // If input value is within the bounds allowed, assign to field.
{ 
    this.c = c ; 
} 
else // Else input value is outside the bounds allowed.
{ 
    this.c = your-default-value-here ; 
}
```

If you cannot specify a default value, throw an exception instead.

```java
if( ( c >= 1 ) && ( c <= 100 ) )  // If input value is within the bounds allowed, assign to field.
{ 
    this.c = c ; 
} 
else // Else input value is outside the bounds allowed. Throw exception.
{ 
    throw new  IllegalArgumentException( "Requires an input value of 1 to 100 inclusive." ) ;
}
```

Full example code:

```java
package work.basil.example;

public class DefaultingInt
{
    final private int count;

    public DefaultingInt ( int count )
    {
        if ( ( count >= 1 ) && ( count <= 100 ) )  // If input value is within the bounds allowed, assign to field.
        {
            this.count = count;
        } else // Else input value is outside the bounds allowed. Throw exception.
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException( "Requires an input value of 1 to 100 inclusive." );
        }
    }

    public int getCount ( ) { return this.count; }  // Getter method (accessor). 

    @Override
    public String toString ( )
    {
        return "DefaultingInt{ " +
                "count=" + count +
                " }";
    }

    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        DefaultingInt di = new DefaultingInt( 101 );
        System.out.println( "di = " + di );
    }
}
```

When run:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Requires an input value of 1 to 100 inclusive.

---

### Java `record`

By the way, for a simple immutable object whose main job is carrying data, consider using the [new records feature](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/395) due to arrive in Java 16 and previewed in earlier versions.

You simply declare the member fields. Java implicitly creates constructor, getters, and overrides of `toString`, `equals`, and `hashCode`.

In a record, marking `final` on a member field is superfluous. Every member field on record is implicitly `final`, a read-only constant, with an implicit getter accessor method. A record is meant to be a non-modifiable nominal tuple (an immutable assortment of named fields). The content *within* an object referenced by a record’s member field may be mutable as with any other class, but the assignment of that one particular object to that member field cannot be changed. Primitives such as your `int` field are not object references, but simply the immediate value, and are immutable when used as a field in a record.

```java
record ClassX( String a , String b , int c ) {}
```

You can still provide your own constructor to run your `if` test for data validation.

```java
package work.basil.example;

public record DefaultingInt(int count)
{
    public DefaultingInt ( int count )
    {
        if ( ( count >= 1 ) && ( count <= 100 ) )  // If input value is within the bounds allowed, assign to field.
        {
            this.count = count;
        } else // Else input value is outside the bounds allowed. Throw exception.
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException( "Requires an input value of 1 to 100 inclusive." );
        }
    }

    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        DefaultingInt di = new DefaultingInt( 42 );
        System.out.println( "di = " + di );
    }
}
```

When run:

> di = DefaultingInt[count=42]

Answer (score 1):

```
this.c = Math.min(100, Math.max(c,1));
```

Comment: Please explain why this can be a solution

Comment: this is a simple way to initialize a variable with values ​​from a given interval

Answer (score 1):

Your `if` is useless.

If you want c to be in the range 1-100 you should change `||` to `&&`

If you want c to be initialised to max or min value every time you can use @A.Alexander solution

Comment: I hand-reported the code so I wrote "or" instead of "and", my mistake in reporting the code